# Counting the number of objects in a list that are divisible by another number

Tags: python, list, for-loop, if-statement

I'm a bit of a newbie here and having a tough time trying to figure this out!

Essentially, I'm looking to have this function count the numbers in a list that are divisible by 2.

```
def listDivide(numbers, divide = 2):
    result = 0

    for i in numbers:
        if i % divide == 0:
            result += 1
            print(result)

listDivide([1 ,3 ,6 ,2 ,4])
```

output is:

```
3
2
```

It appears that the list is being processed through the loop once, correctly counting the objects divisible by 2 (with no remainder using modulo), and then going back through the loop, counting the number of objects in the list based on the index, and then dividing them by 2. Ex, `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`

I've got to be missing something super simple here, but I cant seem to figure it out. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance everyone!

Comment: Better show the *real* output.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In the code you posted, if you want the function to return the count, the missing element is that you are not returning anything. If you `return` instead of print you get:

```
def listDivide(numbers, divide = 2):
        result = 0

        for i in numbers:
            if i % divide == 0:
                result += 1
        return result

print(listDivide([1 ,3 ,6 ,2 ,4]))
# 3
```

As an aside, in Python boolean `False` can be treated as `0` and `True` as `1`. This means if you can turn your list of numbers into a list of booleans, you can just take the sum to get the count. For example:

```
def listDivide(numbers, divide = 2):
    return sum(n % divide == 0 for n in numbers)

listDivide([1 ,3 ,6 ,2 ,4])
# 3
```

This will be a list of bools:

```
[n % divide == 0 for n in numbers]
```

like:

```
[False, False, True, True, True]
```

So the sum of this will be `3`.